# How to test @future methods

Tags: salesforce, apex

I've the following services:

```
public with sharing class LibraryService {

    public static void remove(String jsonString) {
        Library__c library = [ SELECT Id, ilms__Library_Name__c FROM ilms__Library__c WHERE Id = libraryId ] ;

        AccessService.deleteReviewerGroup(library);

        delete library;
    }
}
```

AccessService class

```
public  with sharing class AccessService {
        public static void deleteLibraryReviewerGroup(Library__c library) {

        List<Library__Share> reviewersGroups = [ SELECT UserOrGroupId FROM ilms__Library__Share WHERE AccessLevel = 'Read' AND ParentId = :library.Id  ];
        System.debug('reviewersGroups: ' + reviewersGroups);

        if(reviewersGroups.size() == 1) {
            String reviewersGroupId = reviewersGroups[0].UserOrGroupId;

            delete reviewersGroups;

            AccessService.deleteReviewerGroup(reviewersGroupId);
        }

        return;
    }
    @future
    public static void deleteReviewerGroup(String groupId) {
        List<Group> reviewerGroup = [ SELECT Id FROM Group WHERE Id = :groupId ];

        delete reviewerGroup;

    }
}
```

Now, when I try to test the LibraryService remove method, I keep receiving the below error:

> first error: MIXED_DML_OPERATION, DML operation on setup object is not permitted after you have updated a non-setup object (or vice versa).

```
@isTest(SeeAllData=true)
private class TestLibrary {
    static testMethod void testRemoveLibrary() {
        Library__c library = new Library__c(...);
        Boolean isRemoved = LibraryService.remove(TestUtilsClass.idJson(library.Id));

        System.assertEquals(isRemoved, true);
    }
}
```

I tried adding Test.startTest() and Test.stopTest() to the testRemoveLibrary method, but I still get the same error. Am I doing something wrong? How do I fix this?

Comment: Which line in the above code is throwing the error?

Answer (score 0):

```
@isTest(SeeAllData=true)
private class TestLibrary {

    static testMethod void testRemoveLibrary() {

        Library__c library = new Library__c(...);
        Test.start();
        Boolean isRemoved = LibraryService.remove(TestUtilsClass.idJson(library.Id));
        Test.stop();
        System.assertEquals(isRemoved, true);
    }
}
```

Please add `Test.start` and stop including your method.